# Not able to run ionic platform commands

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to get an ios build for my ionic app (v1 of the framework was used to ). Looking at documentation, it seems like I would have to run the following commands -

```
ionic platform add ios
ionic platform build ios
```

However, running this command gives me a message-

```
The platform command has been renamed. To find out more, run:

  ionic cordova platform --help
```

Thinking that maybe there's been a new update that renamed the commands, I ran `ionic cordova platform --help`, to only get

```
[ERROR] Unable to find command: cordova platform

   _             _
  (_)           (_)
   _  ___  _ __  _  ___
  | |/ _ \| '_ \| |/ __|
  | | (_) | | | | | (__
  |_|\___/|_| |_|_|\___|  CLI 3.0.0


  Usage:

    $ ionic <command> [arguments] [options]
    $ ionic <command> --help (for command details)

  Global Commands:

    docs ................ Open the Ionic documentation website
    info ................ Print system/environment info
    login ............... Login with your Ionic ID
    signup .............. Create an Ionic account
    start ............... Create a new project
    telemetry ........... Opt in and out of telemetry

  Project Commands:

    generate ............ Generate pipes, components, pages, directives, providers, and tabs (ionic-angular >= 3.0.0) (alias: g)
    link ................ Connect your local app to Ionic
    serve ............... Start a local development server for app dev/testing
    upload .............. Upload a new snapshot of your app
    package build ....... Start a package build
    package download .... Download your packaged app
    package info ........ Get info about a build
    package list ........ List your cloud builds

  Options:

    --verbose ........... Verbose output for debugging
    --help .............. Show help for provided command
```

I'm starting to think that it's some weird error with my machine only, as no one has so far reposted this on the web. I get the same messages when I try to run other ios commands like `ionic build ios` and `ionic emulate ios`

Please advise me on how to generate a build so I can test the app in real ios devices.

Answer (score 35):

Figured it out! The right command is

```
ionic cordova platform add ios 
ionic cordova build ios
```

Answer (score 4):

As seen in the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html), you have simply forgotten to add `cordova` to the command:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova platform build ios
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue while adding android device to ionic so followed below command and is working for me.

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have installed cordova
eg: if you are using a package manager like npm.
hit:

```
npm install cordova -g
```

then:

```
  ionic cordova platform add android
  ionic cordova platform add ios
```